# Remove GAC Dependency that does not appear in Prerequisites

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gac

This is so frustrating. For some reason I have added a dependency `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic` into my application so when I deploy it, it gives me the typical "Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly XXX be installed in the Global Assmebly Cache (GAC) first". No big deal.

So I went to the application files section and it doesn't show up. Then I checked my references and nothing shows up. As a last ditch effort I checked under the "Add References" panel and it's not there. For some reason my Build Server has it, but all my end users as well as my development machine do not. Is there anywhere that I can check as to what dependencies are required and remove them? I cant find any code in my application that would required this DLL.

I guess this question can be generalized as this: "What is the best way to find dependencies for a project to prevent new ones from being created"?

Comment: install dotpeek. if you see that assembly there or something close - right click it and say find references.

Comment: It's probably a dependency of one of your dependencies.  Do you include any nugget packages?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are deploying a unit test instead of the product.

Comment: @HansPassant, i doubt that. im the only developer. Its been exactly the same for the last few days

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, now thats a good point. Thats probably what it is, but how can i find the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution that probably doesnt directly solve it for most people, but it is something good to keep in mind. What i didnt realize was that the Visual Studio versions were different and for some reason the one on the build server was adding a bunch of dependencies (like 15). I solved the issue by updating the server to contain the same visual studio version as my development machine.

Comment: I am facing same issue. can anyone tell me what is build server and how to configure it ? i am using vs 2012 professional.